# Registros estão duplicando ao inserir no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, libcurl

Estou fazendo uma API e estou passando por um problema. Ao executar a script que chama a página via cURL, ele faz a inserção de um cadastro no banco de dados, mas ao envez de cadastrar um registro só, ele cadastra 2 iguais.

**cURL.php**

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array('acao'=>'1', 'dados'=>array('nome'=>'Alisson Acioli', 'cpf'=>'xxxx', 'nascimento'=>date('Y-m-d'), 'email'=>'alissonacioli@hotmail.com', 'endereco'=>'xxx', 'bairro'=>'itaquera', 'estado'=>'SP', 'cidade'=>'São Paulo', 'referencia'=>'', 'nomemae'=>'Cecilia', 'cep'=>'08215255', 'endproprio'=>'1', 'nacionalidade'=>'Brasileiro', 'sexo'=>'Masculino', 'nomepai'=>'José Antonio', 'grau'=>'Ensino médio', 'estadocivil'=>'Casado', 'pessoafisica'=>'sim', 'login'=>'alisson', 'senha'=>'123456', 'natureza'=>'1'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/xxxx/api.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

curl_exec($ch);


?>
```

**api.php**

```
<?php
protected function CadastrarUsuario(){

        $dados = $this->dados["dados"];

        //echo json_encode($dados);
        $condition = '';

        foreach($dados as $colunm=>$row){

            $condition .= '"'.$row.'"'.", ";
        }

            $condition = utf8_decode(substr($condition, 0, -2));
            $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cadastros VALUES (NULL, $condition)");

            if($insert){

                echo 'Registro inserido com sucesso!';
            }else{
                echo 'Erro ao realizar registro: '.mysql_error();
            }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Coloque o código onde `CadastrarUsuario()` é chamado.

Comment: public function ExecuteAction(){

  switch($this->acao){

   case 1:

   $this->CadastrarUsuario();

   break;

   case 2:
   echo 'É a ação secundária';
   break;
  }

 }

Comment: No log do webserver existem uma ou duas requisições Http para cada execução do script curl?

Comment: Existe uma só..

Answer (score 2):

Você esta executando duas vezes a função curl_exec($ch);
acho que a ultima função deveria ser curl_close($ch);

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array('acao'=>'1', 'dados'=>array('nome'=>'Alisson Acioli', 'cpf'=>'xxxx', 'nascimento'=>date('Y-m-d'), 'email'=>'alissonacioli@hotmail.com', 'endereco'=>'xxx', 'bairro'=>'itaquera', 'estado'=>'SP', 'cidade'=>'São Paulo', 'referencia'=>'', 'nomemae'=>'Cecilia', 'cep'=>'08215255', 'endproprio'=>'1', 'nacionalidade'=>'Brasileiro', 'sexo'=>'Masculino', 'nomepai'=>'José Antonio', 'grau'=>'Ensino médio', 'estadocivil'=>'Casado', 'pessoafisica'=>'sim', 'login'=>'alisson', 'senha'=>'123456', 'natureza'=>'1'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/xxxx/api.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

curl_close($ch); // <== aqui


?>
```

Comment: Creio que seja isto mesmo!

Comment: Consertei... Coloquei a Coluna "login" como UNIC no MySQL, assim ele não duplica, caso tiver o mesmo login. Obrigado!

Comment: de qualquer forma retire a duplicidade da função curl_exec, pois assim esta executando duas vezes a mesma requisição sem necessidade...